# Comparing methods of aggregating standard deviations

Tags: unbiased-estimator, estimators

**Background Problem**

One of the economic/finance software systems that I am using is adopting the following approach to aggregate standard deviations:

Let $R_t$ be the time series of interest. The software estimates the standard deviation, $\sigma$, of the series in two steps.

1. Step One: Compute a rolling standard deviation of $R_t$. More specifically, let $\hat{W}_j$ be the standard deviation estimator of $R_t$ for a time window of length $T_1$ (e.g., 3 months) ending in time $j$:
   \begin{equation}
   \hat{W}_j^2:=\frac{1}{T_1}\sum_{t=j-T_1+1}^{j}R_t^2
   \end{equation}
   The software apparently assumes that $\mathbb{E}(R_t)=0 \text{ }\forall t$.
2. Step Two: Take the numeric average of $\hat{W}_j$ as the final standard deviation estimator. More specifically, let $\hat{\sigma}_S$ be the standard deviation estimator calculated using $T_2$ (e.g., 5 years worth of) $\hat{W}_j$'s:
   \begin{equation}
   \hat{\sigma}_S := \frac{1}{T_2}\sum_{j=1}^{T_2}\hat{W}_j
   \end{equation}
   The final standard deviation estimator is $\hat{\sigma}_S$.

---

**I Disagree**

I disagree with this approach because $\hat{\sigma}_S$ is a biased estimator, assuming that $R_t$ are I.I.D.

Proof:
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S)=\mathbb{E}(\hat{W}_j) &= \mathbb{E}\Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{T_1}\sum_{t=j-T_1+1}^{j}R_t^2}\Bigg) \\
& < \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\Big(\frac{1}{T_1}\sum_{t=j-T_1+1}^{j}R_t^2\Big)} = \sigma
\end{split}
Strict inequality (Jensen's) holds because the square root function is strictly concave and the distribution of $R_t$ is trivially nondegenerate. $\hspace{10mm} \square$

---

**My Proposal**

I straightforwardly would like to use 
\begin{equation}
\hat{\sigma}_M^2 := \frac{1}{T_2}\sum_{j=1}^{T_2}\hat{W}_j^2
\end{equation}

Despite the fact that $\hat{\sigma}_M^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$, $\hat{\sigma}_M$ is still a biased estimator of $\sigma$ (Jensen's, proof omitted).

However, I am able to prove that $\hat{\sigma}_M$ has a smaller bias than $\hat{\sigma}_S$:

Proof:
\begin{split}
\hat{\sigma}_S^2 - \hat{\sigma}_M^2 &= \Big( \frac{1}{T_2}\sum_{j=1}^{T_2}\hat{W}_j \Big)^2 - \frac{1}{T_2}\sum_{j=1}^{T_2}\hat{W}_j^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{T_2^2} \Big( -(T_2-1)\sum_{j=1}^{T_2}\hat{W}_j^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}\hat{W}_i \hat{W}_j \Big)\\
& =-\frac{1}{T_2^2}\sum_{i<j}(\hat{W}_i-\hat{W}_j)^2 \leq 0
\end{split}

This trivially leads to the following three consequences:

1)  $0< \hat{\sigma}_S \leq \hat{\sigma}_M$

2)  $0< \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S) \leq \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_M) < \sigma$

3)  $0< \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S^2) \leq \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_M^2)$ $\hspace{20mm} \square$

---

**This isn't good enough**

My problem is that I don't know how the Mean Square Errors (MSEs) of the two estimators compare with each other. I tried comparing them using different ways, but each time I hit the same dead end.

1. Attempt I: Direct Comparison
   \begin{split}
   \mathbb{E}\big( (\hat{\sigma}_S-\sigma)^2  - (\hat{\sigma}_M-\sigma)^2 \big) = \Big(\mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S^2)-\mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_M^2)\Big) - 2\sigma\big(\mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S)-\mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_M) \big)
   \end{split}
   This leads to nowhere because I can't decide the sign.
2. Attempt II: Changing the Form
   \begin{split}
   \mathbb{E}\big( (\hat{\sigma}_S-\sigma)^2  - (\hat{\sigma}_M-\sigma)^2 \big) & = \mathbb{E}\big( (\hat{\sigma}_S - \hat{\sigma}_M) (\hat{\sigma}_S + \hat{\sigma}_M - 2\sigma)  \big) \\
   & = \text{Cov}(\hat{\sigma}_S - \hat{\sigma}_M, \hat{\sigma}_S + \hat{\sigma}_M) + \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S - \hat{\sigma}_M) \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S + \hat{\sigma}_M - 2\sigma) \\
   & = \text{Var}(\hat{\sigma}_S) - \text{Var}(\hat{\sigma}_M) + \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S - \hat{\sigma}_M) \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}_S + \hat{\sigma}_M - 2\sigma) 
   \end{split}
   This still leads to nowhere because I still can't decide the sign.
3. Attempt III: Bias-variance Decomposition 
   \begin{split}
    \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}-\sigma)^2 = \text{Var}(\hat{\sigma}) + \mathbb{E}\big( \mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma})-\sigma \big)^2
   \end{split}
   This ends up comparing the variances of the two estimators again.

---

**Challenge**

1) Are there other metrics to evaluate the two estimators?

2) How to deal with the variance of the square root of a random variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Simulation (Monte Carlo) and/or evaluation over a set of long data-series may be most practical here? (I think analytic-type results would be distribution dependent)